# parsing xml in java- multiple child elements

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I want to parse xml elemets using java.I m succeeded in some part...But not sure how to do rest..I have xml as,

```
<MainTag>
    <userid>user1</userid>            
    <country>US</country>
    <city>LA</city>
    <phone>
            <number>1111111111</number>
    </phone>
    <phone>
              <number>222222222</number>
    </phone>
 </MainTag>
 <MainTag>
    <userid>user2</userid>            
    <country>Aus</country>
    <city>MB</city>
    <phone>
             <number>23233</number>
    </phone>
    <phone>
             <number>8787822</number>
    </phone>
    <phone>
              <number>10101</number>
    </phone>
```

I am able to parse xml elements such as country,city etc as below.

```
public void endelement()
{
  if (someText.equalsIgnoreCase("country"))
  {
     pojo.setCountry(Val);
  }
  else if(someText.equalsIgnoreCase("city"))
  {
   pojo.setCity(Val);
  }
}
public void stratelement()
{
   ............
}
```

But in case of phone how I can parse it ? since one user has multiple phone nos.

I want to find multiple phone nos for particular user.

for e.g. in above xml

for user1 there are two phone nos.
for user2 there are three phone nos.

Can anybody help in this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using SAX parsing, please add the SAX tag, too

Comment: I am not sure how you were able to parse this xml. It is not well-formed as it has two root elements

Comment: Since you are converting XML to Java objects have you considered using JAXB?

Answer (score 1):

First, that is not a **well-formed XML** (as it has two root elements) and you can't parse it with any parser API unless it is well-formed. Now, to parse the XML you would normally use the APIs meant for it like SAX, DOM or StAX or even better the JAXB binding API.

Since you seem to be new to this, I suggest you start learning [JAXP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html). Use StAX instead of DOM or SAX.

Comment: You do not require an XML schema to use JAXB (JSR-222):  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Without metadata I think you can go from POJO -> XML. Is the reverse possible?

Comment: JAXB can unmarshal XML without any annotations as long as you specify the class you want the XML unmarshalled to.  You can also add JAXB annotations to your existing Java classes, you don't need to generate them from an XML schema.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan removed the wrong info from post. tx for clarification

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using JAXB, since it appears you are attempting to bind your xml to a POJO.

Looking at the code you have written here (and assuming that the example xml you have provided is a snippet of well formed xml), I am guess that your `pojo` object should have a member for phone numbers that is of type `List<String>`, and your pojo should have a method that allows you to add a phone number to the `List` (perhaps `addPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {...}`)

Comment: Yes i think you are right .I need to have say List phoneList in my pojo.                                                               to which I can add like phoneLis.add(PhoneNos)  ;                    But my que is how can identify perticular phone no is of perticular user ?

Comment: It sounds like a user may have multiple phone numbers.  Anyone of them should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use DocumetBuilderFactory java default class  if you know the incoming xml format for example how many node it has and the names it is very simple look at this code ;

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {

        //documentBuilder instance
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();


        Document dom = db.parse("employees.xml");


    }catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }catch(SAXException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

//and than get root element

```
Element de= dom.getDocumentElement();
```

//get the  nodelist of main element

```
    NodeList nl = de.getElementsByTagName("Employee");
    if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength();i++) {

            //get the employee element
            Element el = (Element)nl.item(i);
}
}
```

//and then get data

```
private void getEmployee(Element el) {

    //for each <employee> element get values 
    String name = getTextValue(el,"Name");
    int id = getIntValue(el,"Id");
    int age = getIntValue(el,"Age");


               //get any element attribute
    //String type = el.getAttribute("type");



}
```

thats all

Comment: This is some sample xml I shown. Actually My requirement is like...I wnated to save in databse user information along with his phone nos. user1 has 2 phone nos user2 has 3 phone nos . I am confused how perticulare phone nos will go against perticular user.

Comment: I m using saxparser...so please suggest me in regard with sax parser how can i handle this ?